# How to solve EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x000000010284d230

Tags: swift, xcode

I use Firebase crash reporting in my app and get lots of crash reports and I am not able to fix this issue.

The crash report itself doesn't give much information so I can understand the issue.

This is the issue:

> Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x000000010284d230
>   specialized CropImageViewController.nextButtonAction(UIButton) -> ()

Also, it gives the line number of the crash. 
On that line I use this code:

```
var scale = (gridView.imageView.image?.size.width)! / 
gridView.imageView.frame.width
```

In this case, the app can crash if the image is nil and you try to force unwrap width property but I am sure that image isn't nil.

so how do I fix this issue? I will appreciate all suggestions.
Thank you

Comment: It's usually not recommended to force unwrap any values, so it's definitely will be an improvement to use ```if let ...``` or ```guard``` statements there. But generally, it's hard to tell where the issue could be here without seeing the whole picture

Comment: livenplay I understand that it would be correct to use optional chaining instead of force unwrapping in this case but it will not help I am sure.

Comment: As livenplay said, even if you are 100% sure that the image is not going to be nil at that point, unexpected cases do show up that haven't been tested. You have nothing to lose if you unwrap the value safely. Moreover, it would be helpful to show what you have in nextButtonAction since its in that method that the exception is thrown, or at least that starts the process of the app crash

Comment: @KarenKarapetyan, as both comments above said. The best thing is to make sure to use optional chaining instead of force unwrapping values. You can even set a simple `print` inside the closures and you'll see if you're even getting a value or not. I would recommend using guard let or if let all the time, to reduce the risk of crashing the app.